# Preserve iframe content scrolling after toggle in Mozilla

Tags: jquery, iframe, scroll, mozilla

I have one parent html page with iframe inside. This iframe is wrapped with div element. I use jquery toggle function to toggle this wrapping div element to hide/show the iframe. The problem is than scrolling parameters of elements inside iframe are not preserved after toggling (If I set some scrollbar on some iframe element it is not preserved after toggling). Mozilla problem only! Is there any solution? Thx for response.

Answer (score 1):

I had this similar issue and solved it by changing the css style of the div through jquery, and changing the place where I put the iframe of google map.

### The problem

The jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(function(){  
        $("#map_link").click(function(event) {  
            event.preventDefault();  
            $("#map").slideToggle();
        });  
    });
</script>
```

The HTML:
I had the link and the google map iframe loaded inline into a div with a display:none css style. Because a display:none style makes the div width:0 and height:0, the address requested in google map doesn't display properly.

```
<a id="map_link" href="#">See map.</a>
<div id="map" style="display:none">google_map_iframe_here</div>
```

### The solution

The jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
    $("#map_link").click(function(event) {  
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#map").slideToggle(); 
        $("#map").html('google_map_iframe_here').css('display','block');
        });  
});
</script>
```

The HTML: The div where I used to put the map now is empty, because I load the map only when clicking on the link, and at that moment I change the css style from display:none to display:block, so the map shows well.

```
<a id="map_link" href="#">See map.</a>
<div id="map" style="display:none"></div>
```

Hope this helps!
Have a good coding day!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try taking the iframe out of the DIV tag, and simply applying your "hidden" state to the iframe itself? You can set it to style="display:none;" to show/hide the iframe...

Comment: Yes, but the same problem. The scrollLeft property related to my scrolling element inside iframe has 0 after iframe or any parent element is set to display: none.

Comment: Moreover, if I perform described situation and then I refresh the page sequentially the scrollLeft value will switch between 0 and original value (value before toggling).

Comment: I think this may have been fixed in Gecko 2; at least, I was unable to reproduce the bug. On the other hand it doesn't surprise me that it doesn't work in older versions, because it's quite possible that the scroll position is saved in a part of the view that is destroyed when you set the display to none.